# iOS: AVAudioRecorder.prepareToRecord() failing with no error

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

`prepareToRecord()` is returning false with no apparent cause. None of the solutions in other similar questions worked for me. Here's what I've tried:

- Starting a recording session (successfully) immediately before creating the `AVAudioRecorder`.
- The output directory exists and is writable.
- These `recordSettings` worked for me in a (now lost) earlier version of my code but recording in general has stopped for some reason.
- I've been using `OpenEars` to do speech recognition but I removed it from the build when I noticed this issue.

Version info:

- iOS 9.1
- XCode 7.1
- Swift 2.1

Here's my code. The output on the simulator and an iPhone is below.

```
func setupRecorder(url : String) -> Promise<Void>? {
    let (doneRecording, recorderAccept, _) = Promise<Void>.pendingPromise()

    let session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    if (session.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")) {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
            if granted {
                print("record permission granted")
                do {
                    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                    try session.setActive(true)
                    self._setupRecorder(url, recorderAccept: recorderAccept)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            } else{
                print("record permission not granted")
            }
        })
    }

    return doneRecording
}

func _setupRecorder(url: String, recorderAccept: () -> ()) {
    print(url)

    let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
        AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue))];

    do {
        let soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url), settings: recordSettings)
        soundRecorder.delegate = self
        if !soundRecorder.prepareToRecord() {
            print("prerecord failed")
            return
        }
        if !soundRecorder.record() {
            print("record failed")
            return
        }
        self.soundRecorder = soundRecorder
        self.recorderAccept = recorderAccept
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("AVAudioRecorder error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

iPhone output:

```
record permission granted
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1DC339E6-555F-47AA-8D4F-4A8E1E847919/Library/Caches/iM3xWVKCGr.aac
prerecord failed
```

Simulator output:

```
record permission granted
file:///Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D035D65-60FA-413E-9CD7-C2C4277EC25F/data/Containers/Data/Application/6DF6374E-3BCF-4BD0-B826-FE1622F134B4/Library/Caches/1ey96W904T.aac
prerecord failed
```

Cache directory permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  53 adrian  admin  1802 Oct 29 14:12 /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D035D65-60FA-413E-9CD7-C2C4277EC25F/data/Containers/Data/Application/6DF6374E-3BCF-4BD0-B826-FE1622F134B4/Library/Caches/
```

I'd love to hear if anyone else has a suggestion.

Comment: Recording previously worked both on the simulator and the device with the above settings. When I get a chance I'll build a new recording app from scratch.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks, Matt.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the bug in my code: `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)`. It should be `NSURL(string: url)!` -- I gave it a `file://` URL as if it were a filesystem path.

Consistent with the other questions about this issue `prepareToRecord()` returns false if the settings are incorrect or, as in my case, there is an issue opening the file for output.